# prove or disprove 3x + 5y = 135 --> x is odd or y is odd:

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can I prove this in words by:
Suppose x is odd, then 3x + 5y will be odd and 135 ——> x is even.
Left side doesn't equal to Right side.
Hence y is odd.

Comment: If not then $x$ and $y$ are even hence so is the sum, contra $135$ is odd. Alternatively mod $2$ it becomes $x+y\equiv 1$ so they have opposite parity.

Comment: Try the contrapositive. That is, prove or disprove: $x$ and $y$ are even implies $3x+5y=135$.

Answer (score 0):

Any integer multiplied by an even number is even. In addition, adding two integers of the same parity (even/odd) is even. Hence, if both $x$ and $y$ are even, then $3x+5y$ is even. This is a contradiction, as 135 is an odd number. Thus, either $x$ or $y$ is odd.

Comment: thank you, I've misread the question.